# iOS TableView cells that are outside the key window at creation doesnt fire didSelect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableView inside a scrollView

1. The tableview is not scrollable
2. The frame height of the tableview is set as the content height of tableview

Everything works fine except the tableview cells that need to be visible after scroll are not firing didSelect functions , whereas the first few tableview cell can fire the didSelect function

Any help :(?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCellA
    cell.setAll(feed: Feed.dummy[indexPath.section])
    return cell
}
```

- The contentsize of scrollview is set to 2000 , which make sure it must be larger than my whole table view frame height for testing
- The delegate & dataSource must work fine because some tableview cell can fire the didSelect function
- I set the tableview frame as below

  > tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)

Comment: Can you post the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` code? Also, what Is your scrollview content size set to?

Comment: Add the code here, so that we can see what is wrong

Comment: the code is added , thanks @Nick

Comment: Is there a reason that the tableview is not scrollable and inside a scroll view? This might cause problems with recognizing the tap.

Comment: @MacUserT , But the weird point is that only some of the tableview cell that are visible after scroll doesnt fire the delegate , whereas the rendered tableview cells did 1

Comment: How are you setting the the content height of the tableview?

Comment: @Carpsen90 I set the frame height of the tableview by tableView.contentSize.height

Comment: What is `tableView.contentSize.height` equal to? Adding any relevant code could be helpful.

Comment: @Carpsen90
it is a native api function from Apple , which return the expected content height of a tableview cell according to the number of tableview cells 

I do not need to set anything on tableView.contentSize.height

Comment: I mean what value did you give it.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I do not give any value to it , it return value to me then I set the value as height of tableview 's frame
I added code to the question now

Comment: Ok what is the returned value. Check with breakpoint.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri It is 910 which is correct frame height that shows all of the table view cells

Comment: I suspect since the tableView's scrolling view is disabled, it is thinking the cells that are outside the key window at creation are not clickable. So not initialized to listen for taps. Better think about doing this some other way rather than having a scroll view inside a scroll view.

Comment: @peter169 - are you using auto-layout for any of your elements? or are you setting frames explicitly?

Comment: did you set `tableview.delegate = self` ? If so see about implementing shouldSelect override and see if that gets hit.